# create ios signing certificate in my certificates

Tags: ios, signing

so - I'm trying to create an automated build for my IOS app - which means I need a .p12 file.

I do the following on my mac:

- create a certificate signing request
- go to apple dev create a certificate
- download it
- import it into keychain

but it always turns up in "certificates", not in "my certificates".  One weirdness is that the email account in icloud isn't in the list in certificate assistant - dont know how that list is created.  Have tried with both distribution and development.

Any idea how I get the certificate to realise I have a private key?

Comment: I don’t know why it doesn’t work, but you should be able get a dev certificate directly from Xcode without all that manual labor.

Comment: Had you added **email** and **name** to generate the **certificate signing request**?

Comment: yes I have added email.   And I'm not using xcode

Answer (score 0):

for anyone facing the same problem - I found the solution.  I have two keychains - login and system.   When I create a csr, the certificate request is going into **login**, but anytime I clicked on a .cer - it was being added to **system**.   When I explicitly added them to the same keychain - it all worked smoothly like it's meant to.